# How to dispose GC Root YES object with 1 unknown path?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, garbage-collection, flash-builder

I am in a very peculiar situation here with my AS3 code. I was profiling my app in Flash Builder 4.5.1 as it seemed that it wasn't GC-ing some objects properly.

Can somebody advice me as to **how to get rid of this object**? Or how to determine what is holding it alive?

- What does **1 Path** mean?
- What is that **GC Root** and how it got there?

I am using robotlegs with IModuleContext, SignalCommandMap, LazyMediatorMap.

[image: Object References]

[image: GC references filter settings]

**EDIT #1**: It could be related to the [robotlegs injector issue](http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/discussions/problems/348-injectors-m_attendedtoinjectees-keeps-objects-alive)... or not, still waiting for some answers. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your BattleModuleContext class code.  It may be an event listener that isn't being removed, but I would like to see your code before making any suggestions.

Comment: As *Brian* metioned, this may come down to a `listener` not having been removed. You can either remove the listener, or set them using a **weak** listener reference. Another idea is to set your `variable` or `property` to null after you are done cleaning/using it.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are indeed removing BattleModuleContext or making it null? As far as I recall Robotlegs needs a Context to operate on, do you set another context and need to remove this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed in newer Flash Player version.

There was GC Root yes on other objects that should be disposed ... and they were, I've just taken Memory snapshot too soon. In next Memory snapshot objects weren't there.

Mysterious Flash Player and its GC....